# Datagridview и столбец base64

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, base64

Подскажите как в данном примере декодировать второй столбец (content) из base64 и вывести оба столбца в datagridview?

```
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
                System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);

                sr.Close();
                string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                string sql = "SELECT datetime(datetime_int,'unixepoch'), content FROM sms";
                var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + filename + ";Version=3;");
                            conn.Open();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    var da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593388/how-do-i-read-a-base64-image-in-wpf

Comment: Если это не то, что вам нужно, то, пожалуйста, уточните вопрос

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что после sql запроса автоматически формируются столбцы для datagridview. Как обработать столбец (в примере он 'content') с зашифрованным base64 содержанием и декодировать его, например, в utf-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если для Вас это еще актуально, то вот стартовая точка, начав с которой, Вы  решите свою проблему:

1. Добавляете дизайнером форм в Ваш dtGridView новую колонку, допустим на позиции (порядковый номер колонки) `decodeContentNum`;
2. На событие `RowValidating`для `dtGridView`  вешаете код:

   ```
   private void dtGridView_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
   {
       int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;

       DataGridViewRow viewRow = dtGridView.Rows[rowIndex];
       DataRowView rw = (DataRowView) viewRow.DataBoundItem;
       if (rw != null)
       {
           DataRow row = rw.Row;
           if (row != null)
           {
               dtGridView[decodeContentNum, rowIndex].Value = MyDecode(row["content"]); //Здесь Ваши преобразования
           }
       }
   }
   ```

где `MyDecode` Ваша функция декодирования.

Это всего лишь схема решения Вашей проблемы, к которой надо приложить собственные усилия. Надеюсь, что она Вам поможет.